# How can I pass an 'e || evt || event' to a nested function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I have a reusable component that takes an onClick event function:

```
const foo = (...params) => event => {
//...process code
};
```

I intentionally built it like this. However, I need the `foo` function on my other function, let's call it `bar` that looks like this:

```
const bar = (type,callback)=> {
 const settings = {
            type,
            callback,
            title:"test",
         };
  foo(settings);
}
```

the above code is attached on an `onClick` attribute of a JSX. I tried the following but no luck:

```
<span onClick={bar('add', handleAdd)}>Click</span>
<span onClick={() => bar('add', handleAdd)}>Click</span>
```

What am I doing wrong? is this possible? how can I pass the event to the `foo` function so that it triggers it.

Comment: You'll want to `return` the `foo(settings)`, then use the first syntax

Comment: ... and use the first of the `onClick` examples.

Comment: Thank you so much, guys. didn't notice that lol

Answer (score 0):

```
// in this way it will be run immediately
<span onClick={bar('add', handleAdd)}>Click</span>


// use this way and call `foo` in `bar`
<span onClick={(event) => bar('add', handleAdd, event)}>Click</span>
```

Comment: yeah. which is why I built it like `function foo () => () =>` notice the two arrow functions - this will prevent the function to run immediately. Which is also good for optimizations. `onClick={()=>bar()} ` will create another object because functions are objects